# Let's go watch the pretty lights of the [aws-aurora]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are two tags for questions that describe the same service:

- [amazon-rds-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-rds-aurora) (811 questions)

  > Amazon Aurora is a MySQL and PostgreSQL compatible relational database management system (RDBMS) that combines the speed and availability of high-end commercial databases with the simplicity and cost-effectiveness of open source databases.
- [aws-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-aurora) (204 questions)

  > Amazon or AWS Aurora is a Relational Database Service(RDS) from Amazon. It is primarily based on MySQL database.

I would suggest merging these into a single tag.

I would additionally suggest that the single tag is named [amazon-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-aurora), which matches how it's described [in Amazon's documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/) – they don't seem to use the terms "Amazon RDS Aurora" or "AWS Aurora" anywhere.

Comment: _The punny titles for tag cleanups are starting to get on my nerves..._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was about to say how we managed to cut down more a lot of amazon a few years back, but I soon realized that you were the reason for it, so without much ado, here's the status:

I renamed [amazon-rds-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-rds-aurora) to [amazon-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-aurora) to match what's there on the documentation. I then added [aws-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-aurora) as a synonym to [amazon-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-aurora), that is:

[aws-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-aurora) (× 204) →[amazon-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-aurora) (× 811)
[amazon-rds-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-rds-aurora) → [amazon-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-aurora) (× 811)

I will be merging the tags after a few days, just to make sure that there are no issues with the synonyms.